# Applying Azure Metric Alerts to multiple Event Grid Topics

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-monitoring, azure-eventgrid, azure-bicep

**I'm attempting to monitor dead-lettered events among multiple Event Grid Topics within an ecosystem**, but can't seem to find a query within Azure Monitor that would output these types of events for alert rule creation at scale - I'm thinking my only option is to set the metric alerts within the Event Grid Topics themselves rather than creating a single alert rule that monitors *all* EG topics. I'd like to complete this task using IaC, but am worried that the only way I could create that is with a PowerShell script that finds all the possible Event Grid Topics within a subscription, and executes a new metric alert command within a loop (so that each Event Grid Topic has it's own alert).

Am I losing my mind here? Any ideas for a better way to get about this task?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azmetricalertrulev2?view=azps-7.2.0#examples), we tried passing multiple `resourceId's of event grid`  to `-target resource scope` flag in `add-azmetricalertrulev2' cmdlet it failed with below error.

[image]

We have tested this in our local environment it is working fine , Below statements are based on the analysis.

You can use the below PowerShell script to create an alert for each event grid topic in the subscription &  to monitor `Dead Letter Events`. The Script will create the following resources

1. create a single action group with email Receivers as notification.
2. creates an alert for all the Event Grid Topics in the subscription with a condition of "DeadLetteredCount>1".

**Here is the Powershell Script:**

```html
$rg="<RGGroup>" ## resource group to for creating action group & alert 

$eventgridlist=Get-AzEventGridTopic 
$eventgridid=$eventgridlist.PsTopicsList.ToArray().id
$windowSize = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5
$frequency = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1

$condition = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "DeadLetteredCount" -TimeAggregation Total -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 1

$email = New-AzActionGroupReceiver -Name "AGgroupactions" -EmailReceiver -EmailAddress "<emailid>"
Set-AzActionGroup -Name "EGTopic_actionGroup" -ResourceGroup $rg -Receiver $email -ShortName "egalert"
$name=1 

foreach( $i in $eventgridid){
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "eventgridalert_$name" -ResourceGroupName $rg -WindowSize $windowSize -Frequency $frequency -TargetResourceScope $i -TargetResourceType "Microsoft.EventGrid/topics" -TargetResourceRegion " " -Description "This is description" -Severity 3 -ActionGroup $actionGroupId -Condition $condition 
$name++
}
```

**Here is the Sample Output screenshot for reference:**

[image]